# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable java

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark

I am trying to add the result to mysql thorugh foreachpartition, but getting the error org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable java.

public class Insert implements Serializable{

```
 transient static JavaSparkContext spc;
public static void main(String gg[]) 
{

 Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
        options.put("url","jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing?user=root&password=pwd");
        options.put("dbtable", "rtl");
 SparkConf ss=new SparkConf().setAppName("insert").setMaster("local");

 spc=new JavaSparkContext(ss);

    JavaRDD<String> rbm=spc.textFile(path);
    // DataFrame jdbcDF = sqlContext.jdbc(options.get("url"),options.get("dbtable"));

    // System.out.println("Data------------------->" + jdbcDF.toJSON().first());


 JavaRDD<String> file=rbm.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
NotSerializableException nn=new NotSerializableException();
    public Iterable<String> call(String x)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return Arrays.asList(x.split("  ")[0]);
    }
});



try {
    file.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<String>>()   {
    Connection conn= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testing","root","amd@123");

        PreparedStatement del = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO rtl (rtl_s) VALUES (?) ");
        NotSerializableException nn=new NotSerializableException();
            public void call(Iterator<String> x) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(x.hasNext())
    {
                String y=x.toString();
                del.setString(1, y);
                del.executeUpdate();
    }
            }

    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I am getting below error

```
6/09/20 12:37:58 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at Insert.java:41
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:919)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreachPartition(JavaRDDLike.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreachPartition(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
    at final_file.Insert.main(Insert.java:59)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: java.lang.Object, value: java.lang.Object@4395342)
    - writeObject data (class: java.util.HashMap)
    - object (class java.util.HashMap, {UTF-8=java.lang.Object@4395342, WINDOWS-1252=com.mysql.jdbc.SingleByteCharsetConverter@72ffabab, US-ASCII=com.mysql.jdbc.SingleByteCharsetConverter@6f5fa288})
    - field (class: com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl, name: charsetConverterMap, type: interface java.util.Map)
    - object (class com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection, com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@6761e52a)
    - field (class: final_file.Insert$2, name: conn, type: interface com.mysql.jdbc.Connection)
    - object (class final_file.Insert$2, final_file.Insert$2@45436e66)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1, name: f$12, type: interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
    ... 12 more
```

I am getting the above error, while trying to update the result to mysql.

Comment: What does `DriverManager` contain? It seems like it can't be serialized.

Comment: Actually it contains the properties of mysql. It has username and password and db name.

Answer (score 0):

When you use some action methods of spark(like map, flapMap...), spark would try to serialize all functions, methods and fields you used.

But method and field can not be serialized, so the whole class methods or field came from will bee serialized.

If  these classes didn't implement `java.io.seializable` , this Exception occurred.
You can find `NotSerializableException` encountered in where by search serialization path.

In your case, you can look here:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: java.lang.Object, value: java.lang.Object@4395342)
```